# Command substitution not working with "test" or "[" or "[[" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have been trying to assign the result (0 or 1) from test command to a variable using command substitution but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a reason for this?

Say I have a file, random_file.txt in my working directory and I test if it exits

```sh
test -a random_file.txt
echo $?
```

Output is 0, which is expected.

And then I tried to assign the result to a variable test_result using command substitution,

```sh
test_result=$(test -a random_file.txt)
echo $test_result
```

Output is empty.

Similarly, when I tried using [[ or [, it won't work as I expected either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test` doesn't write anything to standard output, which is what command substitutions capture. Instead, it sets `$?`.

```
test -a random_file.txt
test_result=$?
```

Using `[` (another name for `test`) or `[[` is the same:

```
[ -a random_file.txt ]
test_result=$?

[[ -a random_file.txt ]]
test_result=$?
```

Comment: I see that makes sense. But the bash manual simply said  that the test command "Evaluate a conditional expression expr and return a status of 0 (true) or 1 (false). " which seems to suggest that it does return something. Is there a source you can point me towards?

Comment: Yes, but command substitution has nothing to do with return statuses. It captures standard output, period. The special parameter `?` exists precisely *because* there is no way to assign the return status of a command directly to a variable. (Commands are not expressions.)

Comment: A return status in shell is a completely different thing from the return value of a function in most other languages, despite the name.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you chepner.